# How to Insert custom date into mysql timestamp field?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have tried to insert date and time string formatted into mysql timestamp field by using following two methods but both shows me 0000-00-00 00:00:00

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-08-05 18:19:03') )
INSERT INTO test VALUES ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2013-08-05 18:19:03', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) )
```

I believe first one should work as I am expecting but not sure why isn't parsing date and time?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` usage, as you can see by doing `SELECT <your unix timestamp stuff>` under mysql. Does your table have more than one column? Or perhaps the data type for the column is something other than int (because that's what `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` returns)?

Comment: Try entering your `INSERT` statements into mysql and see how it responds.

Comment: @GreatBigBore My field is timestamp, it's not a date and time column and there is only one column

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem is that your field is defined as `TIMESTAMP` but `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` returns an int. Use `INSERT INTO test VALUES ('2013-08-05 18:19:03' )` instead.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I am wondering why strtotime php functions works fine but not UNIX_TIMESTAMP in mysql query? When I pass unix_timestamp value in date function it shows me 43 years back date.

Comment: It's probably because the PHP functions you're using are expecting something other than the int that is returned by `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`. Check the documentation carefully and you'll probably find the problem.